# Aborting the task is not stopping the sub process created by celery task

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

From Django, I'm starting the celery task which will trigger the sub process

```
@app.task(bind=True, base=AbortableTask)
def execute_script(self, data: dict):
    script = data.get("input")
    if script and script in get_scripts():
        # Executing related script
        script_path = os.path.join(settings.CELERY_SCRIPTS_DIR, script)
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            f"python {script_path}", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(8)
        error = False
        if process.wait() == 0:  # If script execution successful
            logs = process.stdout.read().decode()
        else:
            logs = process.stderr.read().decode()
            error = True

        return {"logs": logs, "input": script, "error": error, "output": ""}
```

To abort the task, I use below code

```
def cancel_task(request, task_id):
    result = TaskResult.objects.get(task_id=task_id)
    abortable_result = AbortableAsyncResult(result.task_id, task_name=result.task_name, app=app)
    if not abortable_result.is_aborted():
        abortable_result.revoke(terminate=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    return redirect("home")
```

After aborting the task, celery task is stopped but that Subprocess is still running.

Can you guide to solve this problem.